# Scala 3 : Equality compilation error occurring only for certain types

Tags: scala, scala-3

I am trying to understand Scala3 new "Multiversal Equality" feature. I am experiencing inconsistent behavior when comparing different types.

case 1. Compare Int with String:

```
  val x = 1
  val y = "One"

  x == y  // gives compilation error -> "Values of types Int and String cannot be compared with == or !="
```

- Compilation error even without importing `scala.language.strictEquality`
- This compiles in Scala2 without any errors

case 2. Compare two case classes:

```
  case class Cat(catname: String)
  case class Dog(dogname: String)
  val d = Dog("Frank")
  val c = Cat("Morris")

  d == c  // false, but it compiles
```

I am aware of the fact that I need to `import scala.language.strictEquality` to enforce Multiversal equality in case2. But why is it not required in case1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that

case 1. `summon[CanEqual[Int, String]]` doesn't compile even without importing `scala.language.strictEquality`

case 2. `summon[CanEqual[Cat, Dog]]`

- compiles without importing `scala.language.strictEquality` but
- doesn't compile with such importing.

a) Instances of type class `CanEqual` are generated by the compiler (as well as `scala.reflect.ClassTag`, `scala.reflect.TypeTest`, `scala.ValueOf`, `scala.deriving.Mirror.Product`, `scala.deriving.Mirror.Sum`, `scala.deriving.Mirror`)

```
  val specialHandlers = List(
    defn.ClassTagClass        -> synthesizedClassTag,
    defn.TypeTestClass        -> synthesizedTypeTest,
    defn.CanEqualClass        -> synthesizedCanEqual,
    defn.ValueOfClass         -> synthesizedValueOf,
    defn.Mirror_ProductClass  -> synthesizedProductMirror,
    defn.Mirror_SumClass      -> synthesizedSumMirror,
    defn.MirrorClass          -> synthesizedMirror)
```

https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/master/compiler/src/dotty/tools/dotc/typer/Synthesizer.scala#L489-L499

b) The thing is that the case when one of type parameters `L`, `R` of `CanEqual[-L, -R]` is a numeric value class (`Byte`, `Short`, `Char`, `Int`, `Long`, `Float`, `Double`) is handled differently:

```
  val synthesizedCanEqual: SpecialHandler = (formal, span) =>
    ...
    if canComparePredefined(arg1, arg2)
        || !Implicits.strictEquality && explore(validEqAnyArgs(arg1, arg2))
    ...
```

https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/master/compiler/src/dotty/tools/dotc/typer/Synthesizer.scala#L147-L148

Notice that here if the answer is given by `canComparePredefined` then it doesn't matter whether `strictEquality` is switched on.

c) `canComparePredefined` calls

```
def canComparePredefinedClasses(cls1: ClassSymbol, cls2: ClassSymbol): Boolean =
  ...

  if cls1.isPrimitiveValueClass then
    if cls2.isPrimitiveValueClass then
      cls1 == cls2 || cls1.isNumericValueClass && cls2.isNumericValueClass
    else
      cmpWithBoxed(cls1, cls2)
  else if cls2.isPrimitiveValueClass then
    cmpWithBoxed(cls2, cls1)
  ...
  else
    false
```

https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/master/compiler/src/dotty/tools/dotc/typer/Synthesizer.scala#L108-L114

Notice that here if one of `L`, `R` is a numeric value class then the other must be too (taking into account boxing) so that `summon[CanEqual[Int, Int]]`, `summon[CanEqual[Double, Double]]`, `summon[CanEqual[Int, Double]]` compile but `summon[CanEqual[Int, String]]` doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

Universal equality only works for types without `CanEqual` instances already defined. As stated in [Multiversal Equality](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/multiversal-equality.html):

> Even though `canEqualAny` is not declared as `given`, the compiler will still construct an `canEqualAny` instance as answer to an implicit search for the type `CanEqual[L, R]`, unless `L` or `R` have `CanEqual` instances defined on them, or the language feature `strictEquality` is enabled.

and since there is already an instance of `CanEqual` for `String` defined in the companion object as:

```scala
given canEqualString: CanEqual[String, String] = derived
```

universal equality will not work for `String` nor `Int` (as per @DmytroMitin the compiler makes special consideration to Scala's numeric types) even with `strictEquality` disabled.

Comment: `given canEqualString: CanEqual[String, String] = derived` explains why there is `CanEqual[String, String]` but doesn't explain why there is no `CanEqual[String, Int]`.

Comment: @DmytroMitin `canEqualString` exist => `canEqualAny` not used => no `CanEqual[String, Int]` . It does if you include the rest of my answer and not just quote a single line...

Comment: I can't see that. `canEqualString` exists (i.e. there is `CanEqual[String, String]`) => `canEqualAny` is not used for `CanEqual[String, String]`. But why do you think that the latter => no `CanEqual[String, Int]`? For example an instance `CanEqual[Double, Int]` is not defined separately in object `CanEqual` either but `summon[CanEqual[Double, Int]]` compiles (independently of whether `strictEquality` is switched on or swiched off).

Comment: @DmytroMitin I think that what you are trying to say is it could be the numeric at fault here but it's hard to say for me since `CanEqual[String, Cat]` would fail the same for me as `CanEqual[Int, Cat]`

Comment: @DmytroMitin I've updated with considerations for numerics.

Comment: But `Int`, `Double` etc. are irrelevant to `java.lang.Number`. In Scala type system they are just incomparable (with respect to `<:<`) to `Number`. So `given canEqualNumber: CanEqual[Number, Number] = derived` seems to be just irrelevant.

Comment: "I think that what you are trying to say..." No, I'm trying to say that I can't see how your answer explains why `summon[CanEqual[Int, String]]` doesn't compile (independently of whether `strictEquality` is switched on/off).

Comment: By the way, I patched Scala 3 library removing the lines `given canEqualNumber...` `given canEqualString...` and tested that `CanEqual[Int, Int]`, `CanEqual[String, String]` still exist while `CanEqual[Int, String]` still doesn't. So those lines are just optimization (in order to find implicits `CanEqual[Number, Number]`, `CanEqual[String, String]` faster than with generic `canEqualAny[L, R]`). So the lines can't be a part of explanation why some `CanEqual[L, R]` doesn't exist. So I'm afraid currently your answer is not correct (except that you quote docs).

Comment: @DmytroMitin fixed. I was trying to say `CanEqual[Cat, String]` doesn't exist either.

Comment: I'm afraid I still can't see that your answer actually answers the OP's question.

Comment: @DmytroMitin the question is general in which the example happens to compare `Int` with `String`

Comment: OP's question is "But why is it (import scala.language.strictEquality) not required in case1?". Also, given canEqualString is irrelevant, you can remove it from the standard library, behavior will remain the same.

Comment: @DmytroMitin I do believe that `Int` takes precedence in the example but if you are going to the extent of removing code from stdlib then we could also remove the compiler code for comparing numeric types... but that is not my point. I don't see how saying that `String` (or any other type with `CanEqual` instances) would also fail is irrelevant. Thanks for the input anyway but I can only correct mistakes or wrong attribution.

Comment: Well, removing `given canEqualString: CanEqual[String, String]` and observing that the behavior remains is just an easy way to see that "because `given canEqualString: CanEqual[String, String]` is defined" can't be a correct answer (or even a part of correct answer) to the question "why is there no `CanEqual[Int, String]` even without `scala.language.strictEquality`?".

Comment: Reason for why `given canEqualNumber: CanEqual[Number, Number]` or `given canEqualString: CanEqual[String, String]` is irrelevant is easy. What is actually relevant is `def canEqualAny[L, R]: CanEqual[L, R]`. It's nor marked as `implicit`/`given` but compiler makes it implicit (when necessary). If `L=R=String` then both `canEqualString` and `canEqualAny` are suitable candidates and `canEqualString` is preferred as more specific. So `canEqualNumber`, `canEqualString` can be only preferred duplicates to `canEqualAny`. They can't explain why there is no `CanEqual[L, R]` for some `L, R`.